# calculate cubic root using while loop in R

Tags: r

there is some error in my code which makes it go in infinite loop. I tried adding break command but does not work.

```
CubicRoot <- function(x){
 variable <- 1
  while (variable < 5) {
     x <- x^(1/3)*variable
     variable + 1
  }
  return(x)
}
```

Comment: You aren't changing the value of variable, just returning a value of variable+ 1.

Comment: You need to add `variable <- variable + 1` in the loop for that to work.

Answer (score 1):

Add variable = variable + 1, otherwise variable stays constant. So you are running it with variable = 1 over and over again.